# jquery: adding ajax response into dropdown and corresponding text

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a mysql table with the following data

id   Type         Note
1  Technical technical issue
2  Memory    memory issue
3  Part      part number

I get the details from ajax, and want to display the type in a dropdown and the corresponding Note in a text area. Can you advice how I can do that? I am able to display it as a loop of type and note but I want the note to display as the user changes the type from the dropdown.

Below is my current code on ajax success:

```
success: function (data) 
    {
        if( data )
        {
            var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));

             if( obj.length )
            {

                for(var i=0; i < obj.length; i++)
                {

                    tmp7 += " <div class='box' style='border:1px solid ;padding: 5px; margin: 5px'>";

                    tmp7 += "<br/><br/><b>Note Type: <select name='dpnotetype' id='dpnotetype"+ obj[i]['consultid']+"' disabled> <option value= '"+ notetype +"'>" + notetype + "</option>";
                    tmp7 += " <option value='Technical'>Technical</option><option value='Nursing'>Nursing</option><option value='Memory'>Memory</option>";
                    tmp7 += " <option value='Part'>Part</option><option value='Other'>Other</option>";
                    tmp7 += "</select>" ;
                    tmp7 += "<br/> <br/><b>Note:</b><br/> <br/><textarea id='notetext"+ obj[i]['cusid']+"' row='5' style='height:150px; width: 450px' font color='green' disabled>" + notetext + "</textarea><br/><br/>";
                    tmp7 += " <input type='hidden' id='custid' name='custid' value='" + obj[i]['custid'] + "'>";                                           
                    tmp7 += "</div>";
                    }
```

Comment: writing `onchange` event on select box will work here i.e :  send value from select-box to ajax and get corresponding value to display in textarea.

Comment: Hi Swati, thank you. thats exactly what I did to resolve

Answer (score 1):

You are writting notetype in both option
" + notetype + "";

Change notetype to note

" + note + "";

Comment: Thank you Akshma, I decided to go with loading each note value on dropdown menu change event.

Answer (score 0):

to resolve this issue, I decided to use a on change event for each item in the dropdown menu to pull the notes corresponding for each. Didnt require to load all the data at once.